# OneToMany relationship without both entities

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, spring-data

I have and application in which persistence model I've something like this:

Channel -> id, name
Channel_keywords -> channel_id, keywords, last_mod

I'm using hibernate + spring data, and wanted to know how to annotate this example in the channel entity, without creating a new one for channel_keywords. The relationship between both is OneToMany, as one channel can have multiple entries in the channel_keywords table, which makes impossible the use of @SecondaryTable as it's only for OneToOne as far as I know.

The question is, is it possible to achieve this without creating the new entity? or am I wrong about the @SecondaryTable use?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to implement a one-to-many between Channel and ... nothing, because you don't want to map ChannelKeyWord as an entity? No, that's not possible. Why don't you create an entity for ChannelKeyword?

Comment: @JBNizet I just wanted to use something like "SecondaryTable" because you can use the fields right from a form view, for example if I use a web interface to create a new channel and give it the keywords, "SecondaryTable" inserts it directly into the table, whereas if using a relationship between two entities I'll have to update both of them from the same form in the view.